# Forward mouse and keyboard input to X session

Tags: ssh, xorg, keyboard, mouse, input-device

I'm accessing my Pi via SSH.

My network is too slow to actually forward the Pi's desktop back to my laptop, so I have a monitor connected to my Pi. When I `startx` through Putty, I see the desktop on my Pi. All is good.

However, I cannot do anything with this desktop, as all I have is the mouse and keyboard of my laptop.

How can I forward the mouse and keyboard input from my laptop to the desktop on my Pi?

Comment: If you're connecting a monitor anyway, why not connect a keyboard and mouse? You normally use ssh when you when you dont have access to the PI itself.

Comment: @Ash I don't have a keyboard. I know they're cheap and everything, but it would make it easier...

Comment: If you only have a single keyboard and mouse, it might make sense to get a KVM switch so you can go back and forth.

Comment: I'm sure I've written about this before somewhere.

Comment: @Kibbee I thought you couldn't use a KVM switch with a laptop?

Answer (score 14):

You can use a great tool called `x2x`. This essentially treats the monitor connected to the remote device (the Raspberry Pi) as a second `X` screen to you existing session as if you had two monitors connected.

#### Install `x2x` on both devices:

```
sudo pacman -S x2x         # Arch Linux
sudo apt-get install x2x   # Debian/Raspbian
```

#### Configure SSH:

On the Raspberry Pi edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and add/uncomment the following line:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

Then restart the `ssh` server.

#### SSH to the Pi from your other device and run `x2x`:

```
ssh -X 192.168.0.70 'x2x -east -to :0'
```

Replace the IP with the address of your Raspberry Pi.

Now you should be able to move your mouse between the two X sessions by moving your mouse off the screen to the right (east).

Comment: When doing this on both Windows and Ubuntu, I'm getting an error similar to `x2x - error: can not open display :0`. I've installed x2x on the Pi and Ubuntu, and SSH is set up on the Pi.

Comment: @ACarter I don't think you can involve Windows (unless your using xming) as it needs an X session running at each end.

Comment: Do I need to explicitly start the X session on Ubuntu then?

Comment: @ACarter Yes, it treats the connection as an extension of your **existing** X session.

Comment: How do I explitly start it from Ubuntu. Presumeably I don't simply `startx`?

Comment: @ACarter I don't know what you mean. Start what?

Comment: Start X. You said I had to explicitly start X on the laptop.

Comment: @ACarter Yes. X needs to be running. You can start it however you normally do.

Comment: Well Ubuntu uses unity, not X, so I don't normally start it at all. I'll get back to you tommorrow when I have more time.

Comment: @ACarter AFAIK, Unity still runs on X like most other Window Managers (although there was talk of moving to Wayland). Therefore you already have an `X` session running.

Comment: Well I'm stuck on why I'm getting that `x2x - error: can not open display :0` error if I already have X on both ends. I'll have a play around.

Comment: @ACarter I'm sorry about that. It could be something to do with the `DISPLAY` variable. Try typing `echo $DISPLAY` in a terminal and replace the `:0` in the `x2x` command with that output.

Comment: Hmmm, X seems to not open correctly on the Pi. I see the desktop on the monitor connected to it, but the `DISPLAY` variable is not set.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is great! Synergy (the top suggested answer) has a GUI server/client which just sucks, but x2x works neatly from the commandline and out of the box!

Answer (score 10):

[synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) can do this quite well

> Synergy lets you easily share your mouse and keyboard between multiple
>   computers on your desk, and it's Free and Open Source. Just move your
>   mouse off the edge of one computer's screen on to another. You can
>   even share all of your clipboards. All you need is a network
>   connection. Synergy is cross-platform (works on Windows, Mac OS X and
>   Linux).

Comment: How did you build it for the Pi?

Comment: @HeatfanJohn, raspbian has it in the repo

Comment: Ah, `sudo apt-get install synergy` ... cool!

Answer (score 4):

A quick google eventually led me [here](http://www.raspberrypiblog.com/2012/10/how-to-setup-remote-desktop-from.html) and after a quick test this worked for me.

In short you need to setup xrdp

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

Once install it will set the rdp service to start on boot, so restart your RPi. When your RPi has finished booting you will be able to connect to your RPi through Windows built-in (or any other third party) remote desktop application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, that's a neat remote solution, but the idea is that I see the desktop on the screen connected to the Pi, but I can input to this desktop from my laptop's keyboard.

Answer (score 2):

Old thread... I know.

I've written a utility I call `fauxcon`, which forwards your keyboard (and soon, mouse) to the console of another computer you're ssh'd into.

This allows you to view your RPi's display (for instance) on a TV or monitor, and type as if you were logged into the physical device with a keyboard.

Considering everything in my house is wireless, it's rather neat to sit on the couch with laptop and type away, seeing it happen on the big screen on the RPi.

Feedback welcome,

fauxcon - Github - https://github.com/lornix/fauxcon

Answer (score 2):

I was in a similar situation and didn't want to use synergy because I was already running synergy on the computers I wanted to send the keyboard to and don't have X running on the host.  I found uinput-mapper to be the perfect solution for my case.

Github:
https://github.com/MerlijnWajer/uinput-mapper

How-to: 
http://blog.pi3g.com/2014/03/uinput-mapper-redirecting-keyboard-and-mouse-to-any-linux-system-using-a-raspberry-pi/

I used netcat instead of SSH since I'm not too worried about security on my LAN and it seems to intercept the keyboard before you can type your password.  Must be run as root or more ideally just have privilege to mess with input devices.

On the computer in need of a keyboard:

```
# nc -l -p 7005|./input-create
```

Then on the computer with the keyboard:

```
# ./input-read -G /dev/input/eventX -D|nc 192.168.1.122 7005
```

(where eventX is your keyboard and 192.X.X.X is the computer you're sending the keyboard to)

It's had no speed issues and all the keys work correctly.  I believe it works with mice too but I didn't have a need to use that.