# Get Raspberry Pi to automatically recognize USB peripherals

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse, switches

I have a switch to transfer 2 USB inputs between four computers (piB, pi2, pc, and mac). I have only one input connected: an apple USB keyboard with a mouse and a windows keyboard connected into it's two underside USB's. It is a neat setup... however it only works after I manually connect devices and unconnect them (pi side) PC/MAC switch seamlessly... if I manually disconnect the switch, reconnect the keyboard (after I unplug all the peripherals), reconnect the peripherals one at a time, then connect the switch and plug back into the switch I can use everything again. But this is a stupid amount of labour.

How do I make my Pi play with my switch like my other machines do? It is perfectly capable (in the above method) of connecting to a windows keyboard daisy chained into it via an apple keyboard and a USB KVM switch... it just doesn't do it on start. Although it does correctly identify the keyboard and connected keyboards/mice by name during start.

So yes... how do I get the PI to connect to the devices it recognizes and can detect if I manually do that song and dance above? It's not a critical issue... but I would certainly love to know...

Or if anybody has a different solution. I just don't want four mice and four keyboards on my desktop... aside from the clutter I'd have interface issues switching between different products...

Comment: What kind of "switch" are you currently using?

Comment: Are you able to see the Pi's voltage when you switch the keyboard in/out? Maybe the Pi needs more juice to handle the switch over.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B006Z0Q2SI/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1 -- was the one i was using. I fried it and several attached peripherals yesterday -- by trying to plug a USB monitor into the apple keyboard connected to it. If anybody can suggest a better product -- i know that's off topic-- but it would be super duper appreciated lol... and might obviate the need to code around things :)

Comment: and is the voltage a likely issue if i can go through the motions of connecting these in a certain order and achieve connection of all intended devices?

Answer (score 2):

As I understand your question, you have screens on all 4 computers. If they are on the same network, you can play with [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/).

More info in this answer:
[Forward mouse and keyboard input to X session](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4253/forward-mouse-and-keyboard-input-to-x-session/4256?s=3|0.1728#4256)